# Multi Json objects to Angular and display in HTML

Tags: html, json, angular

Hi all can anyone help me put the JSON that contains the products object into angular HTML? I got it to work in the console (see image below) but I don't know how to show the product data in HTML. This is the code I did.

My app.component.html is

```
`<div *ngFor="let product of data.products" style="text-align:center">
   <div> 
    {{ product.id  }}
    {{ product.product_name }}
  </div>`
```

and my app.component.ts is

```
 export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Isham-ColdBanana';
    
      public data:any = []
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    
      }
    
      getData(){
        const url ='https://my-json-server.typicode.com/TomSearle/cb-devtest-api/db'
        this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>{
          this.data = res
          console.log(this.data)
        })
      }
    
      ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? It looks like your `products` property has a nested array within it.  Try doing `*ngFor="let product of data.products[0]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
`<div *ngFor="let product of data.products[0]" style="text-align:center">
  <div> 
  {{ product.id  }}
  {{ product.product_name }}
</div>`
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! luv you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution works but now i get this error on console... anyway to bypass that error?

```
core.mjs:7643 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:69:62)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12114:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:11977:13)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13073:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11767:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:12027:13)
at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.mjs:12094:9)
at tickRootContext (core.mjs:13215:13)
at detectChangesInRootView (core.mjs:13241:5)
at RootViewRef.detectChanges (core.mjs:13757:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I modified app.component.ts to this `public data:any = {locations:[], products:[]}`